# Get assemblies configuration

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a class library that is used as a nuget package. The Nuget package will be used in one or more Web Api's.

I my class library, I want to be able to read the web api's configuration settings.

Can this be done with the `Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()`, which in this case is my web api?

The reason is that the web api's will have a connectionString that they get from Azure Key vault, and I want to read this connectionString in my class library(nuget package). I don't want want to pass the connectionString as a parameter to the nuget package. It should be fixed automagic.

I have tried something like this in my class library:

```
    string path = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().Location; // the web api
    var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(path);
```

But I can't find the connectionString from the key vault here.

Here is the code in my Startup.cs in one of the web api's where azure key vault is added

```
public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json") appsettings.json in.
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        builder.AddUserSecrets<Startup>();  M
    }
    builder.AddKeyVaultConfiguration();
    Configuration = builder.Build();
}
```

The connectionstring looks like this: `Azure:Database:ConnectionString`, and now I want to access this in my nuget package(Class library)

Comment: take in `IOptions` or `IConfiguration` as a depednency. `ConfigurationManager` is out of date and for the .config files.

Comment: @DanielA.White how do you mean?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: @DanielA.White I have read that but can't solve the issue I have. Can you provide an examaple of what you mean?